# TFS - Add work item to specific project

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-workitem

I'm relatively new to developing with tfs (only used git before).

I'm connecting to a server, which contains a decent amount of projects.
When I create a new work item, I can select only the server below 'classification' and not the specific project.

How can I allocate a work item directly to a project instead of the server?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could directly create work item  under the specific team project.  The simplest and effective way is through web portal.

> Project--Work--New Work Item--Work Item Type

[image]

After this the a work item directly  allocated  to this project instead of the server.

> In work item, several features depend on the team project or team that
>   you have selected. For example, dashboards, backlogs, and board views
>   will change depending on the context selected.
>
> When you add a work item, **the system references the default *area* and
>   *iteration paths* defined for the team context**. Work items you add
>   from the team dashboard (new work item widget) and queries page are
>   assigned the team default iteration. Work items you add from a team
>   backlog or board, are assigned the team default backlog iteration.
>
> You navigate to your team context from the top navigation bar.

If you are new to tfs work item, suggest you take a look at related tutorial in MSDN: [Plan and track your project with work items](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/backlogs/add-work-items). Besides in TFS, there is a concept of permission, also make sure your account have enough permission for the project and adding work item.